# Envoy proxy / Move active websocket connection to another upstream host

Tags: websocket, envoyproxy

I'm new user of envoy proxy, maybe someone can help me

I have 2 upstream hosts (UH1 and UH2), and configured envoy proxy to proxy (round robin) websocket connections from a client (frontend) to them.

Let's say UH1 has an active websocket connection (WC1) and UH1 becomes down (closes all its connections) I would like to keep the connection WC1 alive with a client and move the connection to UH2. Could anyone say if it is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in the official google group of envoy-dev team and got an answer from Stephan:

> This isn’t currently supported.
>
> My sense is that one might be able to write an HTTP filter that takes
> the place of the router filter to support this behavior in conjunction
> with upgrade configs[1], but it’s probably a lot of work. That filter
> would probably need to buffer the original HTTP request to be able
> form a new websocket to a different upstream, and it would need to
> decode websocket frames to avoid forwarding partial frames. Further if
> the messages on the websocket are request/response oriented the filter
> would have buffer websocket frames and have knowledge of their content
> to avoid dropping requests.
>
> In my experience, optimizing reconnect from the client and just
> forming a new websocket connection is simpler to implement and also
> provides benefits when the connection between the client and Envoy is
> severed.
>
> Stephan

https://groups.google.com/g/envoy-dev/c/3yCTqLx5ePE